# npm install failed while installing yo jekyllrb: --get remote.origin.url returned wrong result

Tags: windows, node.js, jekyll, yeoman

I am attempting to install jekyllrb using Yeoman, however it grinds to a halt with npm install with the message below. I have added Git to my path and reinstalled everything. I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

```
519 verbose etag grunt-contrib-csslint from cache
520 error git clone git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git Cloning into bare
repository 'C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gruntjs-grunt-contrib-watch-git-19bff6d7'...
520 error git clone git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git fatal: write error: Invalid argument
521 silly lockFile 19bff6d7--gruntjs-grunt-contrib-watch-git
git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git
522 silly lockFile 19bff6d7--gruntjs-grunt-contrib-watch-git git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.git
523 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-svgmin
524 silly registry.get cb [ 304,
524 silly registry.get   { date: 'Sun, 22 Jun 2014 14:23:07 GMT',
524 silly registry.get     server: 'Apache',
524 silly registry.get     via: '1.1 varnish',
524 silly registry.get     'last-modified': 'Sun, 22 Jun 2014 14:23:07 GMT',
524 silly registry.get     'cache-control': 'max-age=30',
524 silly registry.get     etag: '"9UKY9DV2CY0OTZKCLENALCBDO"',
524 silly registry.get     'x-served-by': 'cache-lcy1135-LCY',
524 silly registry.get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
524 silly registry.get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
524 silly registry.get     'x-timer': 'S1403446987.475978,VS0,VE154',
524 silly registry.get     vary: 'Accept',
524 silly registry.get     'content-length': '0',
524 silly registry.get     'keep-alive': 'timeout=10, max=48',
524 silly registry.get     connection: 'Keep-Alive' } ]
525 verbose etag grunt-svgmin from cache
526 error Error: Command failed: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gruntjs-grunt-contrib-watch-git-19bff6d7'...
526 error fatal: write error: Invalid argument
526 error
526 error     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
526 error     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
526 error     at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
526 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
527 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
527 error including the npm and node versions, at:
527 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
528 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
529 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
530 error cwd C:\Users\James\Dropbox\XAMPP\htdocs\jrah.github.io\cv\jk
531 error node -v v0.10.29
532 error npm -v 1.4.14
533 error code 128
534 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: It seems to work when I type "npm update", then I install grunt-contrib-watch (which I believe to be the offender) as npm install grunt-contrib-watch. I followed this blog entry: http://minimaldev.com/how-to-install-jekyll-on-windows/ but it claims I do not have jekyll-1.4.3 when I do. The mystery continues.

Comment: It seems to now demand pygments version 0.5.4.

Comment: I ran into something similar, I ran `npm update` and after that `npm install` worked.  I can only assume that the cache was cleared somehow.